# Number().toLocaleString() constraint

Tags: javascript

I have a problem, I wanted to separate this big number with " , " but tolocalestring leaves zero after 16 digits, how to remove this restriction? Or is there another way to arrange my number?

```js
const input = "92582958294852945892458"
const expected_output = "92, 582, 958, 294, 852, 945, 892, 458"
const actual_output =   "92,582,958,294,852,950,000,000"
```

Comment: Where is the code, what is the exact output, and what did you expect instead? Please update your question.

Comment: Use `BigInt` instead of `Number`.